# Adding custom property to object using MVVM

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-5.0

I am new to MVVM and Silverlight

I have managed to get an example Silverlight application up and running

I return the contents of a table - tblClip into my model (Entity Framework) and an associated object Clip.

Now I have a field on my Clip called Size.  This is an integer which I want to increase by 5x

What is the correct approach to do this and still keep to the pattern?

1) Add a new property such as ModifiedSize on the model and populate it (although not sure where) I assume I would need to decorate it as a DataMember to get it back to the client
2) In the view model, once I have obtained the data from the service agent, go through the clips increasing the size
3) Something else...?

I do not need to save the objects back to the database.

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI specific properties belong on the ViewModel. For example, this is one way you could do it

```
public class ClipViewModel
{
    private int _size;

    public int Size
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set
        {
            _size = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Size");
        }
    }

    public int ModifiedSize
    {
        get { return Size * 5; }
        set
        {
            Size = value / 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Binding to `ModifiedSize` in your XAML would then update `Size` as well as perform `INotifyPropertyChanged` notifications

The other thing you can do is skip the `ModifiedSize` property and use a converter

```
public class ModifiedSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value * 5;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value / 5;
    }
}
```

and then bind to `Size` with the converter

```
<Slider Value="{Binding Path=Size, Converter={StaticResource modifiedSizeConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Hi this is a list of clips not a single clip object?  How would I implement it with a list?

Comment: if you're doing any 2-way binding on the `Clip` object, then you'll need to implement INPC, which means you'd want to convert your `Clip`s to `ClipViewModel`s anyways.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean here!  I dont need know about the property changing, this is simply a new property for display purposes only that will be populated on each object in my list.

Comment: My ViewModel has a Clips property - which is a list, this is then bound to a grid, and soon to be a chart as well

Comment: are you going to 2-way bind to the `ModifiedSize` property? in other words, are you going to bind it to a `TextBox` or `Slider` where the user could change the value? If you are, you'll want use the approach I put above. If not, just add this to your `Clip` object: `public int ModifiedSize { get { return Size * 5; } }`. You'll still be able to bind to the `ModifiedSize` property, but it won't need to be sent across the wire if your Silverlight project has a reference to the same POCO (which I assume it does if your viewmodel has a List of them)

Comment: The user will not be able to change the value.  Its going to be used in a chart.  Clips will be stacked on top each other grouped by month.  Clips can have a size of 1-100, but if I just used the raw size value - a clip of 5 would be tiny!

Comment: Someone has mentioned using an IValueConverter for another of my questions, is that an option here? To use an IConverter in the XAML or would this be classed as hack?

Comment: that's absolutely fine, I actually had just edited to suggest that as well. it's probably the best approach for your particular usage here actually

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12344/discussion-between-paul-and-qntmfred)